# Isn't possible using nested data types (of Elastic Search) inside Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-7

I have some Elastic Search data, and some fields that are nested data type as their mappings. I need to use fields inside nested fields in Kibana. But Kibana doesnt offers me this option. How can I solve this issue?

I fount only this from the [Elastic discussion](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-visualize-lens-not-showing-nested-fields/322691) and tried without luck.
[KO: finding nested fields in Kibana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRqJF.png)

I am unsure how to proceed.